Why is this custom query not working with Elementor?
Using ACF, I have created a custom field for product datasheets.  The custom field is a URL field.  On the product page I enter the link to where the PDF file is being served, in every case it is a dropbox link.  I copy the link, paste it in the field.  This works as intended, the product page shows the datasheet link and when clicked, opens a new tab to show the datasheet.
What I am trying to do now is create a product loop using Elementor Pro loop grid, and filter it to only show products that have a datasheet.  I tried comparing the custom query to '', (blank space) but it didn't work.  So I added a '-' to each products datasheet field.  When I add this custom query to my functions.php file, the query is still pulling the products with the '-' in the datasheet field.  I want to exclude these products, as they do not actually have a datasheet link...
/**
 * Update the Elementor query to filter by 'Datasheet' custom field.
 *
 * @param \WP_Query $query The WordPress query instance.
 */
function filter_datasheet_meta_query( $query ) {
    // Check if this is the query with the ID 'has_datasheet'
    if ( isset( $query->query['elementor_query_id'] ) && $query->query['elementor_query_id'] === 'has_datasheet' ) {
        // Set up meta query to filter out products where 'Datasheet' field is '-'
        $meta_query = array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'datasheet',
                'value'   => '-',         
                'compare' => '!=',
            ),
        );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'elementor/query/has_datasheet', 'filter_datasheet_meta_query' );

Any ideas why this query isn't filtering out the products with the '-' as the value for the datasheet field?
